# Meteor react jest testing

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Simple jest test just to check if the react component can render and it fails because I import

`import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'`

the full error is...

```
 PASS  imports/__partials/Navigation/__tests__/Navigation.jest.js
 PASS  imports/__layouts/AuthLayout/__tests__/AuthLayout.jest.js
 FAIL  imports/features/oAuth/ui/LoginLayout/__tests__/LoginLayout.jest.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor' from 'index.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:142:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (imports/features/oAuth/ui/LoginLayout/index.js:2:41)
      at Object.<anonymous> (imports/features/oAuth/ui/LoginLayout/__tests__/LoginLayout.jest.js:4:40)

 PASS  imports/staticTests/quickCheckboxTest/__tests__/CheckboxWithLabel.jest.js
 PASS  imports/staticTests/quickLinkTest/__tests__/Link.react.jest.js
```

I'm going to assume its because meteor doesn't build and therefore `meteor/meteor` doesn't exist, any help in getting this to work will be appreciated. :)

## Edit...

I was right in my assumption, it's basically because meteor hasn't built the npm modules.

Comment: Okay so I seem to be right, to solve this issue I think I would need to write a driver package for jasmine and run jest when meteor is running... I'm gonna use mocha instead :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can easily stub Meteor modules using the "moduleNameMapper" in your jest config file:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^meteor/(.*)": "<rootDir>/meteorMocks.js"
}
```

And in meteorMocks.js:

```
export const Meteor = {
  call: () => null,
  // ... more stuff you'd like to mock on the Meteor object
};
```

Then you can do

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
```

in your test files.

Just do the same with all modules you need to mock (like `Tracker` or `ReactiveVar`).

Comment: Dude this is old question BUT I like your answer and going to test is ASAP then approve!

Comment: Cheers man :) I came across the same problem and found this. Thought I'd share my solution.

Comment: Here is a blog post by meteor [Real-World Unit Tests with Meteor and Jest](https://blog.meteor.com/real-world-unit-tests-with-meteor-and-jest-3d557e84e84a) explains how to use jest for testing. It is referring back to this answer ;-)

Comment: Do you have a pattern to do the same without the import, using a global variable? It doesn't seem to apply to code loaded from 3rd party packages in particular. It worked for underscore though, weird.

Comment: Also @Michael_Scharf I know you posted this a while ago, but did you hit issues with "core-js" recently? Basically Meteor forcing core-js v2 for some reason while Jest/Babel uses v3 nowadays (see https://github.com/VulcanJS/Vulcan/issues/2270 for our progress on this)